# Is it possible to truncate $remote_user in an nginx access log?

Tags: nginx, log-files, http-authentication

We have an nginx server that, in some contexts, receives sensitive data in the HTTP username field. More specifically, it's an API key that clients are sending like `curl -u "$API_KEY:" ...`.

The default nginx access_log format includes $remote_user, which writes the entire client API key into the access log and taints the file with sensitive data. I know I can define a different log_format that omits the $remote_user variable entirely, however I can see cases where having at least a hint about who the client was could be enormously helpful for log correlation or incident response. Is there a way to configure nginx to store a severely truncated copy of $remote_user in the access log instead of the full value from the client? (i.e. `ABCDEFGH12345678` becomes `ABCD*` or something along those lines.)

(It also goes without saying I don't want to wreck the actual REMOTE_USER type variables that the WSGI backend relies on for authentication.)

This is nginx 1.10.3, as shipped in the default Debian Stretch repos.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the map directive to set one variable based upon another.

I havent tested this, so not sure if Nginx plays nicely with the `{,9}` part of my regex syntax so you might have to adjust it slightly, but something like this should give you a variable with the first 9 characters of the remote_user variable, edit your log format to include the truncated_user variable instead.

```
map $remote_user $truncated_user {
    ~* ^(.{,9}).* $1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@miknik's answer almost worked, but it took a little tweaking and experimentation to actually get it to behave. The full configuration I ended up using is:

```
http {
    [...]

    map $remote_user $truncated_remote_user {
        "~^(?P<tu>.{0,6}).*" $tu;
        default              -;
    }

    log_format combined_trunc '$remote_addr - $truncated_remote_user [$time_local] '
                              '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                              '"$http_user_agent"';

    [...]

    server {
        [...]

        access_log /path/to/access.log combined_trunc;

        [...]
    }
}
```